# Let $U$ be an open subset of $C$ containing $D=\{ z\in \Bbb C :|z|\leqslant 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U$ be an open subset of $C$ containing $D=\{ z\in \Bbb C :|z|\leqslant 1\}$ and let $f\colon U\rightarrow C$ defined by $f(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac {z-a}{1-\overline az}$  for  $a\in D$  and $0\leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi$. 
>   Which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1. $|f(e^{i\gamma})|=1$ for  $0\leqslant \gamma \leqslant 2\pi$.
> 2. $f$ maps $\{z\in C :|z|\leq 1\}$ onto itself.
> 3. $f$ maps $\{z\in C :|z|\leq1\}$ into itself.
> 4. $f$ is one to one.

for $4$ I came $ f(z_1)=f(z_2)\implies (1-a\bar{a})(z_1-z_2)=0$ so if $|a|<1$, $4$ is true I am not able to prove or disprove the other three options, could any one help me or hint me?

Comment: You probably know that, but just in case: this is a subfamily of the so-called [Mobius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223713/problem-on-complex-analysis/227639#227639) and do not worry about the down vote. For $(4)$ you are on the right track.

Comment: :-o :-o :-o :-o

Comment: The question allows $|a|=1$, in which case $f$ is constant.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal how to show $2,3$ are wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The $e^{i\theta}$ factor may be throwing you off. The functions $$\psi_a(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}$$ are very important functions in complex analysis called Blaschke factors.

They have many nice properties, here are three that you should check:

Provided $|a|<1$,

1. $\psi_a$ interchanges $a$ and $0$, so $\psi_a(0)=a$ and $\psi_a(a)=0$.
2. As a map defined on the closed unit disk $D$, $\psi_a$ is its own inverse.
3. $\psi_a$ sends the unit circle to itself.

Given 2 and 3, the rest of your problem should be very easy. 1 is just for fun, though if you study conformal mappings 1 turns out to be a crucial property as well.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you.

Comment: Comment: 3. probably doesn't look like much of a hint. Take $z=e^{i\varphi}$ for some angle $\varphi$. What happens when you factor $e^{i\varphi}$ out of the numerator and denominator for $\psi_a(e^{i\varphi})$? (Note: complex conjugate of a sum is the sum of the complex conjugates.)

Comment: I also notice that $\psi_{-a}=\psi^{-1}_{a}$

Comment: As circle unit Maps to unit Circle so it is one one and onto!

Comment: @Tsotsi In general $\psi_{-a} \neq \psi_a^{-1}$, since this would imply (by 2) $\psi_{-a}=\psi_a$. Check your math.

Comment: 1. and 2. are clearly not true unless $a=0$.  Perhaps you meant the numerator to be $a-z$?

Comment: I had it $a-z$...@Tsotsi Please don't change my answer without good reason.

Comment: could any one clearly tell me how to show wrong $2$ and $3$ in the original question of mine?